# Pointwise convergence of a piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I'm having trouble on a problem about sequences of functions.

Considering the sequence of functions $f_n(x)\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_n(x)=1$ if $x$ belongs to $[-n,n]$ and $f_n(x)=0$ if $x$ doesn't belong to $[-n,n]$.

I seem to think that it will converge pointwise to $f(x)$, that is defined just like $f_n(x)$, meaning $f(x)=1$ if $x$ belongs to $[-n,n]$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x$ doesn't belong to $[-n,n]$.

My doubt is in figuring out $M_n$. I know that it is supposed to be the supremum of $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$, however i do not know which interval to choose from, and because of that i don't know what to substitute $f(x)$ for.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: The function $f$ should not depend on $n$.

Comment: Oh! So should f just be 0, since I need to look at fn when n tends to infinity, so when it doesn't belong to [-n,n]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong limit function (it should not depend on $n$).

If we define the function $f$ as the limit of the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$, then the function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined by $f(x)=1$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

At a specific point $x\in \mathbb{R}$, the limit of the sequence of a function is defined at the point $x$ as the limit of the sequence of numbers $\{f_n(x)\}$.

In this situation, the function $f_n(x)=1$ if $|x|\leq n$, and it equals $0$ otherwise. For a real number $x$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that $|x|<N$ and for every $n\geq N$, $|x|<N\leq n$ so there exists an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f_n(x)=1$ for every $n\geq N$ at every point $x\in \mathbb{R}$. The limit function $f(x)=1$ for every point $x$ in the real line.

To study the uniform convergence of the sequence, we want to see if the sequence $\{M_n\}$ converges to $0$ where 
$$M_n=\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} |f_n(x)-f(x)|$$

However, $M_n=1$ for every $n$ because there exists there is always a real number $x$ greater than $n$ and $M_n\geq |f_n(x)-f(x)|=|0-1|=1$. The sequence does not converge to $0$ so the sequence of function is not uniformly converging.

Comment: Yeah that makes total sense, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that as $n$ grows the sequence of functions looks like the constant function $f=1$ on a larger and larger interval. Certainly, the convergence is pointwise.

Comment: You're right I see it now, thank you!